# How can I align my titles with subsequent rows in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an app that uses Bootstrap 3. In this app, I have a form. The form looks like the following:

```
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><h2>Contact Details</h2></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:1px dashed #eee; background-color:beige;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" />
      </div>                
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:1px dashed #eee; background-color:beige;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The form above renders with the title. Below it, the beige rows stick out on the left-and-right sides. Essentially, a row is 1170px. I need to use the grid system. But, I need to include column boundaries and colors as well. This is causing the problem. The columns and rows need to be consistent with the positioning of the form title. How can I do this with bootstrap?

Basically, I want this:

```
Contact Details

+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

However, I'm getting this:

```
   Contact Details

+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstraps rows have a margin of 15px to the left and the right, the col-md-6 class has a padding of 15px to both sides:

```
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px
}

.row {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

So if you want to get rid of that 30px on each side, simply set your div to `padding: 0` and the row div to `margin: 0` and you will have it.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal elegant solution to this would require a parent selector, which doesn't exist in CSS yet, but does exist in jQuery. That being said, as far as your provided code is concerned, this will move your titles over 15px to the left to counteract the inherent padding added by Bootstrap:

```css
.col-md-6 h2 {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```